How to resolve the mistmatched input 'token' expecting 'LEXER_RULE'
I have the following grammar defined in ANTLR4 (g4):
grammar SimpleExpr2;

expr: entityName '(' paramList ')' SEMICOLON;

entityName: ENTITY_NAME;

paramList: param (SEPARATOR param)*;

param: PARAM_NAME ':' DATA_TYPE
     | PARAM_NAME;

ENTITY_NAME: [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*;

PARAM_NAME: [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*;

DATA_TYPE: 'int'
         | 'string'
         | 'float'
         | 'date'
         | 'text'
         ;

SEPARATOR: ',';

SEMICOLON: ';';

WS: [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip;

Using the following input
entity( parametros:int, parametro:int, paramtrico:float, paramtri);

Apparently it works but the result shows the following errors:
line 1:4 mismatched input 'parametros' expecting PARAM_NAME

line 1:20 mismatched input 'parametro' expecting PARAM_NAME

line 1:35 mismatched input 'paramtrico' expecting PARAM_NAME

line 1:53 mismatched input 'paramtri' expecting PARAM_NAME

The result tree shows the RED color over these tokens

How can I resolve this issue?
The grammar originally had a different order in the rules definition, it was reordered to try to resolve it. For example, initially the same error was with the ENTITY_NAME, but now is with the parameters.

ENTITY_NAME: [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*; PARAM_NAME: [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*; These two lexer rules overlap. ENTITY_NAME always "wins". Antlr lexers are not parser-state sensitive. For practical purposes, an Antlr lexer tokenizes the entire input before the parser does anything with the token stream input. Therefore, you cannot "direct" how the lexer recognizes the input via the parser rule param: PARAM_NAME ':' DATA_TYPE | PARAM_NAME;. Just define ID: [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*; and use it throughout. Look at https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4 to get an ideal of how to write a grammar.

@kaby76 seems to be helpful but if you create ID, how can you differ when you will walk the expression between a PARAM_NAME and an ENTITY_NAME? I tried PARAM_NAME : ID; and ENTITY_NAME: ID; but the error still appearing.

[H]ow can you differ when you will walk the expression [...]?. When using Antlr Visitor's or Listener's, you cannot based on token type alone. Besides, you can only override the tree walking for an internal parse tree node, not for a specific a parse tree leaf node. You should read how Antlr lexers work. You should also add EOF to the end of a start rule.

Do it like this:
param
 : param_name ':' DATA_TYPE
 | param_name
 ;

entity_name : ID;
param_name : ID;

DATA_TYPE
 : 'int'
 | 'string'
 | 'float'
 | 'date'
 | 'text'
 ;

ID : [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*;

Also note that DATA_TYPE has to come before ID.

I think you answer is correct, because before came here again I tried entityName : ID and it works, the problem is when you use ENTITY_NAME : ID, because uppercase is for lexer rules and not for parser rules, where the entityName is a parser rule really. Same as you have in the code you posted: entity_name : ID

Correct: in case of ENTITY_NAME : ID, there is no real change compared to your original way. Do not the fact that DATA_TYPE has to be placed before ID. Otherwise input like int would also become an ID.
